# ng-include after application load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have a server using handlebars to create an initial HTML page. In this page, I wish to have a `ng-include` to update the page on the client.

However, whenever my application runs, it loads the page, so the `data-ng-include="template.url"` loads template.url as it normally would. Is there anyway for ng-include to load this data after my application loads?

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DIkTCBClqQ4K4Ne8CEIp?p=preview). Look at the code inside index.html!

Comment: what you are looking for can be done using a router, or more specifically, a state machine.  Angular includes a router package, and there is a great package ui-router that is a state machine https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router.  either will work, but many people consider ui-router superior to the default angular router.

Comment: @Claies Will have a look and get back to you!

Comment: personally i dont like ng-include, what I would do is build a directive and either use ng-if like answer suggested (so directive is rendered on condition) or just update a variable in the directive and then run $compile on the template  or something to render the directive and bind it to scope

Answer (score 1):

you can use

[ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) directive

just check for it initial loading , it will make your life easy

```
<ANY ng-if="expression">

 //your code goes here

</ANY>
```

such as

```
<ANY ng-if="false">

// code will not execute 

</ANY>
```

i hope this will help you

on your code

```
<body>
<div data-ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div data-ng-include="template.url" ng-if="false">

    Here is some stuff that I wish to remain until I press the button below.
  </div>
  <button type="button" data-ng-click="second()">Press me!</button>
</div>
```

based on your answer you should use your condition at your .js file  here is your modified code

```
 angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

$scope.templates =
  [ { name: 'first.html', url: 'first.html'},
    { name: 'second.html', url: 'second.html'} ];

    if (false){
      $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
    }


$scope.second = function () {
  $scope.template = $scope.templates[1];
};

$scope.first = function () {
  $scope.template = $scope.templates[0];
};

 }]);
```

Comment: Interesting this would work. Unfortunately, it also disables the rest of the code!

Comment: did you try like this ?? check the answer again

Comment: Ahh haha sneaky sneaky! I unfortunately have logic inside of the `ng-include` div though (on my application, the plunker was a simplified example) :(

Comment: then you must set condition at your .js file not here , for less complexity

Comment: Check the answer now , did you see the checking at your first load ?

Comment: The button however needs to be inside of the `ng-include`(and functioning ofc)!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91334/discussion-between-nur-farazi-and-karl-morrison).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) for your case, but for no more edited for your code, i can provide this solution for you:

1. Remove your code inside index.html file, so your code become like this:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html ng-app="myApp">
   <head>
      <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.6" data-semver="1.4.6" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div data-ng-controller="ctrl">
         <div data-ng-include="template.url"></div>
      </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

2.Replace your script.js become like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

$scope.templates =
  [ { name: 'init.html', url: 'init.html'},
    { name: 'first.html', url: 'first.html'},
    { name: 'second.html', url: 'second.html'} ];
$scope.template = $scope.templates[0];

$scope.second = function () {
  $scope.template = $scope.templates[2];
};

$scope.first = function () {
  $scope.template = $scope.templates[1];
};
}]);
```

3.Create file init.html with code inside:

```
 Here is some stuff that I wish to remain until I press the button below.
 <button type="button" data-ng-click="second()">Press me!</button>
```

4. Run it.